# Why is inner display mode of `table-cell` not customizable?

Tags: css, css-tables

This is a question about the CSSWG specification. I am looking at this one: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#the-display-properties

I am struggling to understand why `table-cell` is as inflexible as the other `table-*` modes. Why is the inner display type fixed to `flow-root`? It would seem reasonable that `display: table-cell` would be treated as an outer display mode and default to `table-cell flow-root`, but allow overrides such as `table-cell flex` or `table-cell grid`.

Is there something in the layout logic that prevents this? Or just has no one bothered to allow customization of `table-cell`'s inner layout?

Comment: This would probably be better addressed to https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues. The implementation of the table layout algorithms is known to be a minefield though. It's quite likely that browser makers simply didn't fancy the complexities of trying to implement such combinations. I've seen that given as a reason for not providing other combinations.

Comment: @Alohci: According to fantasai, supporting this at least in Gecko would be, in her words, "trivial" - there's been discussion of this on their GitHub Issues alongside other display types: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3940

Comment: @BoltClock - Thanks for the link. I don't see fantasai saying that there though. I see "That's much harder. :) Table captions just lay out like regular blocks, for the most part. Table cells participate in table layout algorithms, which are mostly a mystery of multi-decade multi-layered reverse-engineering.", which is more or less what I suggested. Also, the resolution from that issue was "no to table-cell since it's too hard."

Comment: @Alohci: Oh, you're right. The words I quoted were someone else's that she was quoting. That person had gone and written an implementation, but it wasn't approved. Hm.

Comment: @Alohci thanks, I considered that but wanted to check if it's more of a beginner question before creating an issue there.

Comment: @BoltClock awesome! I failed to find it myself because I used the `css-display-3` label filter that was included in link from the spec.

Comment: @Džuris: Yeah I think they made it a css-display-4 issue instead.